# How to sum all rows into a total column without a set number of columns?

Tags: vb.net, datatable, sum

I'd like sum up all rows in a datatable with out a for each because the number of rows can be very big.
The number of columns is unknown, so i can't simply add all the row(columns) + row(Columns)...

Col1 Col2 Col3 Total
1    2.11 3.11  6.22

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Hope to hear from you.

Comment: There's no way without a loop, no matter if you see it (`For...Each`) or not(LINQ).

Comment: Is the type of these columns `Double` or `String`?

Comment: It's a Double type

Answer (score 0):

You can't sum all columns of all rows without loops, that's technically impossible. Maybe you think that LINQ could magically do it without a loop. But it is also using loops, you just don't see them.

However, following should work if those columns are of type `Double`:

```
Dim doubleColumns = table.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn).
    Where(Function(c) c.DataType = GetType(Double)).
    ToArray()
Dim totalSum As Double = table.AsEnumerable().
    Sum(Function(row) doubleColumns.Sum(Function(c) row.Field(Of Double)(c)))
```

I guess that the `Total`-column was just there to show us a sample row.